# ANTLR4 : Syntax Error, '<' came as a complete surprise

Tags: antlr

I try to use the Java.g directly written by Terrence (https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java/Java.g4). And I will use this grammar in ANTLRWorks (http://tunnelvisionlabs.com/products/demo/antlrworks). In this code, I got the error

> "Syntax Error,  '<' came as a complete surprise"

```
|   <assoc=right> expression
    (   '='
    |   '+='
    |   '-='
    |   '*='
    |   '/='
    |   '&='
    |   '|='
    |   '^='
    |   '>>='
    |   '>>>='
    |   '<<='
    |   '%='
    )
    expression
```

Answer (score 1):

That means that ANTLRWorks2 is slightly out of date and uses an earlier version of ANTLR. I think Sam will be updating soon.